# How to dynamically populate mongoose document reference at runtime?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a schema that has a field that could reference different schema.

```
var HistorySchema = new Schema({
  type: {type: String, required: true},
  objectId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  changed: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed}
})
```

The documents of this schema allows me to keep track of changes happens in different `types` of objects with `objectId`.

For example, if `User` has changed `name` from 'John' to 'Steve', a `History` document would have:

```
{
    type: 'User',
    objectId: '55fa6bf0831ba3fa0879e7e8',
    changed: {name: {oldValue: 'John', newValue: 'Steve'}}
}
```

Obviously, `type` can be many different things.
My question is, can I *magically* `populate` the objectId field without knowing `type` before the query?

I know I can do:

```
History.query({...}).populate('objectId', null, 'User').exec(...);
```

But that requires me to know the `type` is `User` when the query is constructed.

And obviously I can do a second query manually given the `type` and `objectId`.

For example, is it possible to save the `ref` type of a document (not schema) at runtime and take advantage of that? I look around and don't seem to find a way.

Comment: If you added the model name of `objectId` as another field in your schema, you should be able to do something automatic using post find [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).

Comment: Yes, as illustrated above, the modelName is `type`.

Comment: Duh, don't know how I missed that. :) Then you should be all set to be able to do this in post find middleware by using [`Model.populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate).